# PHP file not uploading

Tags: php, file, upload

I don't mess with PHP alot, but I don't see what's wrong with this. I had this same exact code working about 15 minutes ago, but now it just stopped working. I didn't change anything, so I'm a little confused.

Anyways, It's a form and you are supposed to submit a screenshot, here's the code for my form,

```
<form method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Screenshot of them agreeing to terms:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I don't think anything is wrong with that. Here's the PHP that handles all this (I think/hope)

```
 if(isset ($_POST['loanee'])) {
            if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    $name = md5_file(sys_get_temp_dir() . $_FILES['tmp_name']);
      move_uploaded_file(sys_get_temp_dir() . $_FILES["files"]['tmp_name'], "public_html/mc/images/{$name}.jpeg");
    }
  }
```

I am not getting anything echoed to me, and no errors are showing up in the error log, so what's wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Loanee is not the problem, as my sql database IS being updated after the picture is "uploaded", I didn't put the whole form, as some of it has some information I don't think is necessary, the form is working fine as I said before, sorry to everyone that keeps telling me that loanee isn't set in the form, it is.

Comment: You should give the uploaded file the proper file extension. `.jpeg` is not correct for all three of them.

Comment: where is the element that has name **loanee**  in your form on which you are applying the **isset($_POST['loanee'])**

Comment: I think you have another typo in the last line of code. You access the `_FILES` variable in two different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `sys_get_temp_dir()`. The `$_FILES["files"]['tmp_name']` will already point to the temp dir.

So change your code to something like this:

```
$name = md5_file($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'], "public_html/mc/images/{$name}.jpeg");
```

**Edit**: Oh, and you should use [is_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) to check whether or not a file has been uploaded.

Comment: I get an error saying Filename cannot be empty on line 46, this is line 46   `$name = md5_file($_FILES['tmp_name']);`

Comment: @Austin Oh yeah, you have to reference it the same way as with move_uploaded_file.. eg. `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']`. Will fix that in my answer

Comment: Fixed it now.. the key for the `$_FILES` array should be the same as your form-input field. So in your case it's "file"

Comment: Now I get these two errors, `Warning: move_uploaded_file(public_html/mc/images/7485273b2147c49e10271596d2b1d764.jpeg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/mc/CreateLoan.php on line 46

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpWUwCoI' to 'public_html/mc/images/7485273b2147c49e10271596d2b1d764.jpeg' in /public_html/mc/CreateLoan.php on line 46`

Comment: Your path is wrong. If your script resides in `public_html/mc`, your path should be relative to that (eg. just `images/{$name}.jpeg`), or use absolute paths instead. Also make sure the directory is writable for php scripts (usually by making it writable by the "web-process" user).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where `$_POST['loanee']` gets set, but it needs to be set. Otherwise the interesting code is just skipped.

Comment: Sorry, It is being set. That part is working correctly (I am updating a sql database after picture is uploaded) Should've said that before.

Comment: Austin, is it part of the same form though? If it is not enclosed under the same form tag, clicking on submit may not give you all the variables you want.

Answer (score 0):

At the first line of your php script you check for the `loanee` variable that is supposed to come from the HTML Form, but you don't have any field in your form with that name.

More specific :

```
if(isset ($_POST['loanee'])) {    // That line does not correspond to any input element into your form
```

To solve your problem either remove that statement control or add a new field into your form with that name.

Comment: It's in the form, I just didn't upload the whole form. I updated my first post. Sorry, I just didn't think the whole form would be necessary.

Comment: Try to disable that statement control in order to check if the uploading still working. If working then you can focus on that statement